# Craft Commerce 2 - extend Order details page

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, craft-pro

Let's say we're on the order details page with the 3 tabs - Order Details, Transactions, Status History

How do I add an extra tab with content?

Craft V3 / Commerce V2

Thanks

Comment: You mean with custom content or with an additional field layout tab?

Comment: I don't know - a tab that I can click which opens custom content @RobinSchambach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include additional tabs you can include several different field layout tabs in your field layout designer. When you open `/admin/commerce/settings/ordersettings` you can see the field layout for your orders. There you can click on `+ New Tab` and drag and drop the fields you like